# Decidability of the solvability of quadratic systems

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, decidability

Let a finite collection of (complex) unknowns $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be given, as well as an affine system $AX=B$ in the quadratic variables $X:=[x_i x_j : i\leq j]$, with entries in a computable subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Is there a way of deciding whether the system has a solution? If the answer is positive, is there an *efficient* way, without resorting to general Gröbner basis algorithms (which in general fail to solve the systems I have at hands, *e.g.* Maple and Sympy implementations) to solve it?

Comment: This is decidable (e.g., by quantifier elimination for algebraically closed fields). However, you can reduce the satisfiability of arbitrary polynomial systems to quadratic systems by introducing extra variables; so solutions certainly do not lie in a tower of quadratic extensions.

Comment: Thanks Emil, I removed the last part of my post. Also, I gather that solving quadratic systems is as difficult as solving general ones, hence there probably is no specific algorithms out there.